# Difference between adduser and usermod -G -a

Tags: command-line, groups, adduser, useradd

What is the difference between

```
adduser user_name group_name
```

and

```
usermod -G -a user_name group_name
```

At first glance they seems to do the same thing : add a user to a group.

Comment: `usermod -G -a user_name group_name` would be wrong either way. I think you'd want `usermod -G group_name -a user_name` or `usermod -a -G group_name user_name` instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`adduser` and `usermod` are two different utilities which have in common the fact that both can add a user to a group.

According to [man adduser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/adduser.8.html)

> `adduser` is **friendlier front ends to the low level tools** like
>   `useradd`, `groupadd` and `usermod` programs.

More info:

> - [man adduser](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/adduser.8.html) : `adduser`, `addgroup` - add a user or group to the system
> - [man usermod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/usermod.8.html) : `usermod` - modify a user account

Comment: ok so, the two commands I give do exactly the same thing ?

Comment: @snoobdogg What is meant is that they are different.  `usermod` cannot add a user to the system like `adduser` can.  They just happen to share the ability to add a user to a group.

Comment: ok I get it, but the two commands I give in my question do the same thing yes or no?

Comment: @snoobdogg - you can add a user to a group using the two commands as you specify in your question. Those two commands differ in various other parameters.

Comment: @snoobdogg Yes, they are the same commands.  From the `adduser` man page:  `If called with two non-option arguments, adduser will add  an existing user to an existing group.`

Answer (score 5):

At first glance, yes.

At second glance, `usermod -G -a user_name group_name` is not correct.

The `-G` option should be followed by the group name(s).

```
$ sudo usermod -G -a nogroup muru
[sudo] password for muru:
usermod: group '-a' does not exist
$ sudo usermod -a -G muru nogroup
usermod: user 'nogroup' does not exist
```

The `-a` can come before `-G`, or after the group name(s), but not between `-G` and the group name(s).

As a side note, `adduser` itself uses `gpasswd`:

```
$ grep gpasswd $(which adduser)
    my $gpasswd = &which('gpasswd');
    &systemcall($gpasswd, '-a',$existing_user,$existing_group);
```